# how to show google map in webpage using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I want to display google map in page load that why i m using  window.onload Function.I am passing latitude and longitude as static,and try to show in a div with an id ="map_canvas".But nothing is shown on webpage. Where M i making mistake.Here is my code.I am unable to fetch Google Map in my webpage.

```js
Here is the java script.

<script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
    </script>


    <script>

      


        window.onload = function WindowLoad(event) {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        }

       
      
    </script>
```

```html
    
this is my Html Code.
<div id="map_canvas"></div>>
```

Comment: did u check any error in console?

Comment: yes i did but there is no error, i m getting the value   in map variable  but i didn't understand  how should i use the var map to make this code work

Comment: My code is working properly now....i was missing style in my div....thnku

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add height and width to the map_canvas div and then check...

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
```

Comment: Do i need to make Google api   by myself  . Can u please help.I m getting nothing in my webpage...

Comment: no need of that. Google provides v3 api which you can use without api key.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the Google API key in the query parameter. Your script tag should be something like this:

src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBeEeKz4H-KQTFABe1UTs9h5KUlpqsZ10Q&sensor=false"

You can register for a free Google map API key, which gives about 10,000 free hits everyday, good enough for practice purposes.